# Cannot save string to file on android

Tags: android, file, mkdir

I am trying to create txt file and write to it on sdcard in android. I am getting "Directory not created" error. `path.mkdirs()` should create needed directories, shouldn't it ? I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and I have turned on storage permission for app.

Android version: 7.0

```
public void addData(View v) {
    wordList.add(inAddWord.getText().toString());

    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    File file = new File(path, "wordDatabase.txt");

    try {

        if(!(path.exists() && path.isDirectory())) {
            while (!path.mkdir()) {
                Log.e("Path", "Directory not created");
            }
        }

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        os.write((inAddWord.getText().toString() + "\n").getBytes());
        os.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also place a toast in that catch block to inform the user when that catch happens.

Comment: `while (!path.mkdir()) {
                Log.e("Path", "Directory not created");`. Wrong code. Your app will hang if the directory cannot be created. It makes no sense to try again and again. Change while to if. And add a toast to inform the user if mkdir fails. And return. It makes no sense to continue. Please adapt your code and update here too.

Comment: `if(!(path.exists() && path.isDirectory())`. No. That should be `if(!path.exists())`.

Comment: It works now, thanks. File was created on internal storage where I wasn't looking because I thought that `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` returns only directory to SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android 6+ you should add code to ask the user to confirm the permissions you request in manifest.

Google for runtime pemissions.

Comment: Of course you will see that toast with 'Directory not created'. You should only call mkdir() or mkdirs() if the directory does not exist. Moreover you should also check the return value of mkdirs() and not continue with your code if the directory is not created. You should display a toast then and return. Please adapt your code. Test it and then adapt your code here.

Comment: Done. Still does not work. Now app does not do anything after running function. No file or directory created.